# How to directly convert asn1 schema to xsd?

Tags: java, xsd, grammar, data-conversion, asn.1

I have a full `asn1` schema needed to be converted to XSD

How to do that in java without using any `asn1` tools?
I tried `antlr` library but it didn't work for me and tried this `asnti` code

I have `asn1` schema

I have `asn1` binary file

I have the decoded output from binary file

```
 private static void loadDataFile(
     final File berFile, final AsnSchema asnSchema, final String topLevelType) {
     try {

         logger.info("Loading file: " + berFile.getCanonicalPath());

         final ByteSource byteSource = Files.asByteSource(berFile);
         final ImmutableList < AsantiAsnData > pdus =
             Asanti.decodeAsnData(byteSource, asnSchema, topLevelType);
         for (int i = 0; i < pdus.size(); i++) {

             logger.info("Parsing PDU[{}]", i);
             final AsantiAsnData pdu = pdus.get(i);
             for (final String tag: pdu.getTags()) {
                 try {
                     logger.info(
                         "\t{} => {} as {}",
                         tag,
                         pdu.getPrintableString(tag).get(),
                         pdu.getType(tag).get().getBuiltinType());
                 } catch (final DecodeException e) {
                     logger.info(
                         "\t{} => {} as {} (as HexString because {})",
                         tag,
                         pdu.getHexString(tag).get(),
                         pdu.getType(tag).get().getBuiltinType(),
                         e.getMessage());
                 }
             }
             for (final String tag: pdu.getUnmappedTags()) {
                 logger.info("\t?{} => {}", tag, pdu.getHexString(tag));
             }
         }
     } catch (final Exception e) {
         logger.error("Exception loading data file: " + e.getMessage());
     }
 }

 /**
  * This function will take a schema file and run it against the data file(s) passed. If dataFile
  * is a directory then it will load all files in the directory (against the schema), and recurse
  * directories. This will attempt to ignore/skip files that are not ASN.1 BER files. This will
  * not propagate exceptions, will only log them.
  *
  * @param rootFile either a directory or ASN.1 BER binary file to decode
  * @param asnSchema schema to decode against
  * @param topLevelType the name of the top-level
  */
 private static void handleDataFile(
     final File rootFile, final AsnSchema asnSchema, final String topLevelType) {
     for (final File file: Files.fileTraverser().depthFirstPreOrder(rootFile)) {
         try {
             if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                 final String name = file.getCanonicalPath();

                 // I don't really know what the 'right' file extensions are, so let's just rule
                 // out
                 // some of the ones that we have come across that are not BER files!
                 if (!name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".bmp") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".asn") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pcap") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".rtp") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xlsx") //
                     &&
                     !name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")) {
                     loadDataFile(file, asnSchema, topLevelType);
                 } else {
                     logger.debug("Ignoring file: " + name);
                 }
             }
         } catch (final Exception e) {
             logger.error("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
         }
     }
 }

 /**
  * Test parsing an ASN.1 schema file
  *
  * @param asnFile file to parse
  * @throws IOException if any errors occur while parsing
  */
 private static void testReadingAsnFile(final File asnFile) throws IOException {
     final CharSource schemaSource = Files.asCharSource(asnFile, Charsets.UTF_8);
     final AsnSchema asnSchema = AsnSchemaReader.read(schemaSource);

     logger.info("User testing:");
     final BufferedReader reader =
         new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, Charsets.UTF_8));
     while (true) {
         System.out.print("\tEnter raw tag: ");
         final String rawTag = reader.readLine();

         ImmutableSet < OperationResult < DecodedTag, String >> results =
             asnSchema.getDecodedTags(ImmutableList.of(rawTag), "PS-PDU");
         OperationResult < DecodedTag, String > result = results.iterator().next();
         logger.info(
             "\t{}:\t decode {} => {}",
             result.wasSuccessful() ? "PASS" : "FAIL",
             rawTag,
             result.getOutput().getTag());
     }
 }

 /**
  * Test parsing a BER file
  *
  * @param berFile file to parse
  * @throws IOException if any errors occur while parsing
  */
 private static void testReadingBerFile(final File berFile) throws IOException {
     final ByteSource byteSource = Files.asByteSource(berFile);
     final ImmutableList < RawAsnData > data = Asanti.readAsnBerData(byteSource);
     int count = 0;
     for (final RawAsnData rawAsnData: data) {
         logger.info("PDU[" + count + "]");
         final Map < String, byte[] > tagsData = rawAsnData.getBytes();

         for (final String tag: Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(tagsData.keySet())) {
             logger.info("\t {}: 0x{}", tag, BaseEncoding.base16().encode(tagsData.get(tag)));
         }
         count++;
     }
 }

 /**
  * Returns the Command Line Options for this application
  *
  * @return the Command Line Options for this application
  */
 private static Options getOptions() {
     return new Options().addOption("h", "help", false, "Print out help");
 }

 /**
  * Performs application validation against the provided command line. If the validation fails
  * then an appropriate exception will be thrown (ParseException or subclasses)
  *
  * @param cmdLine the command line passes to main
  * @throws ParseException if there are issues with the options or arguments
  */
 private static void validateCommandLine(final CommandLine cmdLine) throws ParseException {
     if (cmdLine.hasOption("h")) {
         throw new ParseException("");
     }

     if (cmdLine.getArgs().length != 1 && cmdLine.getArgs().length != 3) {
         throw new MissingArgumentException("Must specify 1 or 3 arguments");
     }

     // All good!
 }

 /**
  * Prints the usage message
  *
  * @param footerMessage adds to the footer of the message, useful for specifying known issues
  *     with usage.
  */
 private static void printUsage(final String footerMessage) {
     final String callPattern =
         "USAGE: asanti [options] <asn_schema_file>" +
         NEW_LINE +
         "    asanti [options] <asn_ber_file>" +
         NEW_LINE +
         "    asanti [options] <asn_schema_file> <asn_ber_file> <top_level_type>" +
         NEW_LINE +
         NEW_LINE +
         "Where:" +
         NEW_LINE +
         "    asn_schema_file        the ASN.1 schema file to parse (must end in '.asn')" +
         NEW_LINE +
         "    asn_ber_file           the ASN.1 BER file to parse (must end in '.ber')" +
         NEW_LINE +
         "    top_level_type         the name of the top level type in the schema file";

     final HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
     formatter.printHelp(callPattern, "Options:", getOptions(), NEW_LINE + footerMessage);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please edit this question and fix the serious formatting issues. You cannot expect others to take time over your question unless you do.

Answer (score 0):

ASN1 schema and XSD files are interchangable, officially so, according to an ITU standard that says how the translation is to be done. The commercial ASN.1 tools freely injest either ASN.1 schema or compatible XSD schema.

There's a free (registration required) online converter [here](https://www.obj-sys.com/), look under Products -> Free Web Tools